# If you have a physical address, is it possible to traverse the paging structures backwards and compute a linear address?

Tags: paging, virtual-memory, address-space

So, my question is a bit ridiculous I guess and crazy.

I don't see why you ever need to go from a physical address back to a linear one.

Nonetheless, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In systems with an inverse page table, that is quite simple. For others, you'd either have to scan the operating system's allocation table or the the page tables to find it.

It is possible.

Keep in mind that a single physical page frame may have multiple logical addresses.